# Conditional Hibernate Interceptor

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, interceptor

I have a Hibernate `Interceptor` that is persisting property changes of an entity and is working correctly.  I am looking to update its current logic and only intercept when it's being triggered from a particular method, not just when Hibernate views it as being 'dirty'.

I am looking to implement something equivalent to:

```
@Override
public boolean onFlushDirty(Object entity, Serializableid, Object[] currentState, Object[] previousState, String[] propertyNames, Type[] types){
   String callingMethod = // determined somehow... 
   if(callingMethod == MyService.updatePerson) {
      // Only persist changes when calling method is updatePerson
   }
   return false
}
```

I've looked all around SO and the web, but I have not been able to find anything on the topic.

I've looked into controlling this behavior with AOP, however the interceptor fires blindly

Is anyone aware of being able to trigger an interceptor based on the calling method?

Comment: Can you please add more details? What events does your Interceptor intended to intercept? Calling method - is that an entity member? Method of some service? Maybe re-formulating your question in the way like 'I need to perform X before going to persist when that happens inside MyService.doSomething' may also help to understand the problem better

Comment: @Kostiantyn - Thank you for your feedback.  I've updated my original post.  My interceptor is working as designed.  My question is more about refining when it gets fired.  I'm trying to have it only intercept when it's being called from a particular method.

Comment: Well... It is not how things are typically done with Hibernate, but you can try obtaining Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace() and search for particular method name within returned array of StackTraceElements. However, that may not work as onFlushDirty for changes actually made within updatePerson may be triggered later after exiting the MyService.updatePerson. That depends on FlushMode and on approach to transaction management used. In general case, there is no guarantee at all that changes made to entity can be easily tracked down to a method which authored them.

Comment: Would it not be easier for `entity` to have an `isPropertyChangeAuditable()` method, which can be queried inside the interceptor, and set to `false` whenever and wherever property changes are not required to be audited?

Comment: @manish -   Yes, that would work and will be my approach to take at work today.  I thought about doing that yesterday within AOP, but I'd have to create both an `Interface` and `Abstract` class in order for this to work.  Some of the entities already extend from abstractions so I would have to fix all those classes.  I was hoping for something that didn't require extensive changes in the existing code.  Thanks!

Comment: @Dan are you setting the interceptor using the property hibernate.session_factory.interceptor?

Comment: '
LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean fb= new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean(); fb.setDataSource(ds); 
// setters 

Map<String,Object> props = new HashMap<>();
props.put("hibernate.ejb.interceptor", entityInterceptor);
fb.setJpaPropertyMap(map); 
return fb;
`

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating an `Abstract` class and `Interface` to support setting the 'isEditable' method I need.

I then wrote a custom annotation that I use within AspectJ to trap all executing code that I want.  Within the pointcut, I update the entity, setting the 'isEditable' method.

Now, when my interceptor fires, I do a quick check to see if that entity is editable, if not, I dont persist the changes into the history table.